# How to create multiple mysql database users in a docker-compose file with in a single container?

Tags: mysql, database, docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a docker-compose file with more than one service(WordPress,nocodb) required a mysql database, but I don't want to create individual containers(mysql) for each services. I'm planing to use a single mysql container with multiple users. So, how can add multiple users using docker-compose

Comment: The whole point of docker-compose is to assemble multiple out-of-the-box images into a "cluster" as needed, without tweaking each image. Running multple services in a single container is certainly possible and easy to do, but you would be missing the point of docker-compose.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand your question. You want one single container on the machine to be re-used by all your `docker-compose` stacks? *I don't want to create individual containers(mysql) for each services* <- This doesn't make much sense. You would have one db service for all the other containers to use normally.

Comment: i want to use one sql container to run multiple services

Answer (score 5):

First of all the whole concept of docker is to isolate each service into separate containers.

However, by using a volume to add sql files into the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder, all the `.sql` files would be called by the `mysql` image entrypoint script.

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./<your-path>/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

You could then add a file `./<your-path>/init/01-users.sql`

```
# create your root user
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'local';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
# create other users
CREATE USER '<username>'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
# grand appropriated rights
```

and a file `./<your-path>/init/02-databases.sql`

```
# create databases
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `<first>`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `<second>`;
```

Comment: is there is any way to connect containers running with docker-compose to mysql localhost without exposing ip to public